# In R, is there a method to split a data frame by a column, evaluate an expression and return the result as a list?

Tags: r, split, expression

So say I have a data frame...

```
d <- data.frame(
  x   =   c(10, 15, 20), 
  n    =  c(30, 30, 30), 
  group = c(1 , 2 , 3 ))
```

... and I want to split this data frame by `group`, and specify an expression that will be evaluated within each subset (like with `with`), and return the results as a list.

**Is there a function / simple combination of functions / dplyr & purrr pipeline that would do this?**

You can accomplish this using base R functions by combining `by` with `with`. The following statement will give you a list of the results from three `binom.test`s:

```
test_results <- by(d, d$group, with, binom.test(x, n))
```

but to me it looks a bit obfuscated and reading this a couple of weeks from now I would be confused about what's going on. So what I'm looking for is some "cleaner" way to accomplish this.

Comment: You can combine `split()` and `lapply()`, i.e. `lapply(split(d, d$group), ...)`

Comment: `lapply` requires a function, not an expression, which means you would have to "unpack" the data frame yourself like `lapply(split(d, d$group), function(part) {binom.test(part.x, part.n)})`.

Comment: `lapply(split(d, d$group), function(part) binom.test(part$x, part$n))`

Answer (score 0):

See http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html

Basically:

```
d %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  tidyr::nest() %>%
  mutate(stuff = purrr::map(data, function(df) binom.test(df$x, df$n))
```

But for your examples this also should work (not tested)

```
d %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(stuff = list(binom.test(x, n)))
```

Additionally you can look at `broom` package to tidy up the results from binom.test.

Comment: Thanks for the examples! But these functions do not return a list, but a data frames. I wasn't especially interested in `binom.test`, that was just an example of a functions returning a "complex" data structure.

Comment: If `res <- d %>% ...` then `res$stuff` returns your list. `data.frames` are not more than column lists of equal length (of number of rows)